# List of Events - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose a game involves rolling of 2 dice. 
First Player rolls dice, the second player must roll the higher number (sum of dice), and then the first player must roll the higher number to stay in the game, and so on. The first player failing to roll the higher number than his opponent, loses.

I am trying to enlist all the possible sequences of the rolls.
Obviously, the longest string consist of 11 rolls (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12).

I have calculated the 10-rolls sequence number, and the 9-rolls, and so on, but I need listing of all possible sequences. Is it possible to do this with Excel ?(except doing it manually, of course).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I apologise, that was not my intention (frankly, I don't even know what is script). Please delete the question if you see it appropriate, as I cannot even attempt doing anything but the manual entry.

Comment: Rather, you could attempt improving the question by showing what you have attempted so far or some pseudocode showing how you think the problem could be solved.